# Unable to run .htaccess file in netbeans in a java project?

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, .htaccess, netbeans

This is my .htaccess file for  Leverage browser caching :

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I have placed my .htaccess file under Web Pages in Netbeans.When i am uploading war file on server and checking performance of my site using gtmetrix i can still see the caching issue.That means server is not recognizing my .htaccess file.Is there any problem with syntax or is there any other error.I am using hibernate and glassfish for my project.

Comment: Does glassfish recorgnize .htaccess files at all? I don't know really much about it, but i think htaccess is restricted to Apache only. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Cheesi That what i am asking at SO.

Comment: I googled and found the following on SO: ".htaccess is an Apache HTTPD feature. As far as I know there isn't anything comparable in GlassFish." So I think, you are not able to do this.

Comment: @Chessi actually i am trying to improve performance of my site.It is built on glassfish so i can't change it is there any alternative.

Comment: As cited in the comment above, it seems there is no htaccess alternative, but I just found something, may that help: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Q_27580443.html and http://www.moreofless.co.uk/far-future-expiry-static-content-java/

Comment: @Cheesi Sorry that didn't work